# Help with my time series ARX model prediction?

Tags: time-series, matlab, autoregressive

I have created an ARX-model where I predict the nitrogen oxide levels based on past values of nitrogen oxide with past exogenous input values nitrogen dioxide, temperature, atmospheric particulate matter, etc.

This might be a straightforward question, but I started to wonder if for example my ARX-model would be the following:

$$ Y_{t} = \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}Y_{t-1} + \alpha_{2}Y_{t-2} + \beta_{1}X_{t-1}^{1} + \beta_{2}X_{t-2}^{1} +  \gamma_{1}X_{t-1}^{2} + \gamma_{2}X_{t-2}^{2} + . . . $$

Where Y:s correspond to my past values of nitrogen oxide(NO) and the X:s correspond to different exogenous input values.

Now if I have data available until time t on all time series and I want to make predictions until say time t+10, won't I need to first predict all the future values of exogenous inputs? After I have predicted the exogenous values I can start to predict the NO-levels with my model correct?

So I'm predicting predictions with predictions? :)

I'm very new at this and my question might be stupid x) Please comment if my question is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to predict your predictors.  You can build a model for each of them and use the forecasts to drive your equations prediction.

Answer (score 1):

I am no chemist, but I imagine that future values of nitrogen oxide (your target variable) could in part be determined by nitrogen *di*oxide... but also vice versa, so your target variable and your "exogenous" variable influence *each other* (so the "exogenous" variable would not be really exogenous any more). This might call for [Vector Autoregression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) or similar models.